# Is there any Pseudocode or examples on how to implement NORMSDIST function of Excel?

Tags: excel, cdf, probability-distribution

Does anyone have some information or either some equations on how to implement `NORMSDIST` or `NORM.S.DIST()`? 
There is an equivalent of NORMSDIST in Matlab, and there are libraries in Python and Java, I am trying to implement it in PHP, so some pure equation would be very useful.

Comment: see    https://support.office.com/en-us/article/normdist-function-126db625-c53e-4591-9a22-c9ff422d6d58

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I've checked that one but apparently it is not useful. I have implemented it in my code and it does not give me the same results.